# Laravel Mailable sending mail multiples times when it should send once

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp

I'm using Laravel 9. I made a system where an admin evaluates a player, it sends him a mail saying that he is accepted at the website.

In the view, when admin clicks accept, it goes into the evaluations controller and sends the mail if the value is the value of accept.

Controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) {
        $evaluation = Evaluation::findOrFail($id);

        $evaluation->approved = $request->approved;

        $evaluation->save();

        if($evaluation->approved == 3) {
            $user = User::findOrFail($evaluation->idUser);
            $user->evaluation = 1;
            $user->save();
            Mail::to($user->email)->send(new EvaluationMailable());
        }

        return view('admin.evaluaciones');
    }
```

View:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('evaluation.update',$evaluaciones->id)}}">
    @csrf
    <input type="text" name="approved" value="3" hidden>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary bg-primary">Aceptar</button>
    @method('PUT')
</form>
```

What some users received:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add verification upon the value of the evaluation to check if it has not already the value 3 which seems to meet the criteria you "need" to send an email.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) {
        $sendMail = true;
        $evaluation = Evaluation::findOrFail($id);
        if ($evaluation->approved != 3) {
          $evaluation->approved = $request->approved;
          $sendMail = false;
        }
        $evaluation->save();

        if($sendMail && $evaluation->approved == 3) {
            $user = User::findOrFail($evaluation->idUser);
            $user->evaluation = 1;
            $user->save();
            Mail::to($user->email)->send(new EvaluationMailable());
        }

        return view('admin.evaluaciones');
    }
```

It may prevent sending multiples emails with the same form to the same evaluation / user.

Comment: The thing that I'm doing is, 0 not sent, 1 sent, 2 deny, and 3 accepted, that's why I'm saving always the value of approved.

Comment: So, you're only sending evaluations whose value is approved==0 (not sent) and only in this case you are updating its value to 3 (accepted). Your mail trigger will then look for every mail to be sent (evaluation == 3) and update the value to 1 (sent).
Perhaps the problem is more on your trigger taking into account to many time the evaluations to be sent before the value is updated.